# How to bind from Swift view model to Obj-c view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa 4.1.0, and I'm interfacing a (new) Swift view model with a (legacy) Obj-c view controller.  I'm having issues using `RACObserve` to observe String properties from the view model.  I can't use `MutableProperty` because the view controller is in Obj-c.  The `RACObserve` `subscribeNext`'s fire once upon first setting the properties, but after changing them, no signal seems to fire.  I have basically:

In View Controller:

```
[RACObserve(self.viewModel, buttonTitle) subscribeNext:^(NSString *title) {
    // Do something
    }];
```

In View Model:

```
init() {
   self.buttonTitle = "Original Value"
}
func foo() {
   self.buttonTitle = "Changed Value"
}
```

I see a fire for the original value, but never the changed value, even after putting the change in a Signal Producer and observing using `observeOn(UIScheduler()).start()`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure that any property observable through KVO is marked as being `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

RACObserve is based on KVO.If you want to use KVO in swift, class should inherit NSObject class.
[KVOImplementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002307-BAJEAIEE)

As @David Rodrigues said:

```
dynamic var buttonTitle: String?
```

Comment: My view model is inheriting from `NSObject`

Comment: As @David Rodrigues said:`dynamic var buttonTitle: String?`